# Event Espresso Query Modification?

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I am using Event Espresso with WordPress.
May u help me out in further query modification?
Hope you will :)

I want to use meta_query to list events on page.
Somewhat like below code.

```
$atts = array(
    'title' => NULL,
    'limit' => 10,
    'css_class' => NULL,
    'show_expired' => FALSE,
    'month' => NULL,
    'category_slug' => NULL,
    'order_by' => 'start_date',
    //'order_by' => 'end_date',
    'sort' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
           'key' => 'start_date',    
           'value' => '2017-01-08 08:00:00',              
           'type' => 'DATETIME',  
           'compare' => '>=', 
         ),
       )
  );
```

I want to implement search functionality for Event Espresso and i have those fields:
State - Dropdown (How to list all state? May be Venue)
Category -  Dropdown
Start Date - Datepicker
End Date - Datepicker
Keyword - input

On submit those values will be submitted and based on those , i will get filtered events that are related with those values.

So how to implement this? 
Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: No one in Stackoverflow world?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly delayed response to this...

First, this depends on the version of EE you're using. They support both EE3 and EE4. I use EE4, so any reference to code I make is specific to version 4.

In order to create an events archive with a filtering functionality, you'd need to use the EE events archive. EE uses custom database tables and a lot of different post types to achieve what you see, so creating a simple archive with these filters won't work very well. Very little is stored in the _posts and _postmeta tables and you need to get post meta from related post types and tables that aren't laid out like WP_Query likes. They have a shortcode for the events list, which is [laid out here](https://eventespresso.com/wiki/ee4-shortcodes-template-variables/) and has a lot of the filters you're looking for, but no search functionality.

Their support forum has a lot of snippets and such created by their staff and there's a (long) related post about formatting the events archive page [here](https://eventespresso.com/topic/editing-the-event-list-and-event-page/#post-178759). You'll also need to go through [this documentation](https://gist.github.com/lorenzocaum/0a35fe4997992fdb1dc5) to see about their custom methods and hooks.

You could copy over and modify the archive templates they describe in a child theme to add search functionality to the top of the page. This would allow you to directly override the archive. You'll need to make use of some fancy filters, which are covered pretty clearly [over on WPMU Dev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-post-filters/).

The pieces of information you're looking for for filtering are here, minus keyword:

```html
<?php
 if( have_posts() ){
  while ( have_posts() ){ the_post(); // enter the WordPress loop
   
   $id = get_the_ID(); // get the ID of the current post in the loop, post ID = EVT_ID

   $terms = get_the_terms( $id, 'espresso_event_categories' ); // get the event categories for the current post
   if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $cats = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     // do something
    }
   }

   $event = EEM_Event::instance()->get_one_by_ID( $id ); // get the event OBJECT using EE's existing method

   $venue = $event->venue(); // get the venue object for the current event
   $state = $venue instanceof EE_Venue ? $venue->state_abbrev(); // get the event venue's state, but you can use state_name() to get the full name             

   // using the event to get the first and last date for the entire event. Sub $datetime for $event to do it per datetime
   $start_date = $event->start_date('j M Y'); 
   $end_date = $event->end_date('j M Y');
   $start_time = $event->start_time(get_option('time_format'));
   $end_time = $event->end_time(get_option('time_format'));
   ?>

   <!-- Do some awesome layout stuff here -->

   <?php
  }
 }
 espresso_pagination();
?>
```

This will give you the meta for each post within the loop as variables, but you may want to pull them into pre_get_posts. You can just as easily create an array of $events and then filter it using the variables.

I'm not sure what your exact needs are regarding keyword. Do you mean tags? Title keywords? Description search? You'll need to narrow down exactly what you need this to do in order to write a function for it.